# .NET development in Kubuntu

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, programming

Hello Ubuntu community

I am a student at collegue, and I want to use Kubuntu as my main OS. Because I am programming .NET (.net 5 is ok), I need .net framework, developer pack, and Visual Studio (the ide of choice for my school). I've heard that .NET 5 has native Linux support, but I can't find Visual Studio on Microsoft's website (for linux then). Is there a not too hard way to edit my files and compile (and debug) my programs?

Thanks

Irsu85

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: I can't use visual studio code, only VS (2019)

Answer (score 1):

.NET as a framework is cross-platform from Core releases. But if you're talking about IDEs then Visual Studio is not supported on Linux so far (although there is an open issue in github on that).
Nevertheless, if you want to develop using .NET on Linux, you can use Rider IDE, Visual Studio Code and some other text editors/IDEs.

Comment: Thank you, although it is a bit too late for me. Rider is indeed a good alternative, although it's paid. But VS code is a bit basic for c# editing...

Comment: Yeah, sorry I’m a bit late :D. Nevertheless Rider has free Community edition which I believe has most of frequently used functionality. VSCode can also do the job if you install some C# extension, but of course it would not be near VS in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio isn't for Linux Distributions. I use C# and programmer in VSCode. You can install`ms-dotnettools.csharp` in your code and install .net in the machine. The intelligense is very good and you don't have problems for to development with .Net

Comment: Did you literally say two oppisite things?

Comment: @Irsu85 Carlos most likely meant that Visual Studio does not support Linux, not Visual Studio Code.